# Include the name of my interlocutor in my query (messaging system)

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I've a messaging system (1v1) on my website and I want to join some informations about my interlocutor (name, avatar, etc.).

My structure is more than common:

Threads:

```php
    Schema::create('threads', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');            
        //...
    });
```

Participants:

```php
    Schema::create('participants', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->integer('thread_id')->unsigned();
        $table->integer('user_id')->unsigned();

        $table->foreign('thread_id')->references('id')->on('threads')->onDelete('cascade');
        $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users')->onDelete('cascade');
    });
```

To get my Threads I've this query:

```php
    Thread::select(
        'users.name',
        'threads.id',
        //...
    )->join('participants', 'participants.id', '=', 'threads.id')
    ->join('users', 'users.id', '=', 'participants.user_id')
    ->where('participants.user_id', '=', $user->id)
    ->get();
```

Of course, because of my `where` condition, it's my name and not the name of my interlocutor. How can I join the informations of my interlocutor and "exclude" mine?

PS: Please don't give me a messaging system package. I want to code it myself.

---

**Edit:**

Relation in my model Thread :

```php
public function users()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\User', 'participants', 'thread_id', 'user_id');
}

public function participants()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Participant', 'thread_id', 'id');
}
```

---

**Edit 2:**

@Jonas Staudenmeir code:

```php
$threads = Thread::select(
    'threads.id',
    'threads.last_sender',
    'threads.is_read',
    'threads.last_message',
    'threads.date'
    )->whereHas('users', function($query) use($user) {
    $query->where('users.id', $user->id);
})->with('users')->get();

foreach($threads as $thread) {
    $interlocutor = $thread->users->where('users.id', '!=', $user->id)->first();
}
```

Trying to get the fields I only need:

```php
$threads = Thread::select(
    'threads.id',
    'threads.last_sender',
    'threads.is_read',
    'threads.last_message',
    'threads.date'
    )->whereHas('users', function($query) use($user) {

    $query->select('users.id') // May be its gonna run faster
    ->where('users.id', $user->id);

})->with('users')->get();

foreach($threads as $thread) {
    $interlocutor = $thread->users->select(
        'id',
        'name',
        ...
    )->where('users.id', '!=', $user->id)->first();
}
```

$intercolutor give me this error : `Method Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection::select does not exist.`

Comment: Are you familiar with relationships in Laravel? They would simplify queries like this.

Comment: @JonasStaudenmeir Yes, i've these relations (check my edit), but no idea how to use it. $threads[0]->users() give me nothing, I mean i've the dump of BelongsToMany but no data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```php
$threads = Thread::select('id', 'last_sender', 'is_read', 'last_message', 'date')
    ->whereHas('users', function($query) use($user) {
        $query->where('users.id', $user->id);
    })
    ->with('users:users.id,name,avatar')
    ->get();

foreach($threads as $thread) {
    $interlocutor = $thread->users->where('id', '!=', $user->id)->first();
}
```

Comment: I had to modify your code because the `id` was ambiguous for mysql (check my **edit 2**). I tried to optimize both query by adding the fields, but for interlocutor I got an error. It's possible to select the fields I only need: name, avatar,etc. or no? Otherwise I seeded my tables and it's look like its working. I hope its the best way because I will have ~400 users on the message system o_o`.

Comment: Thanks for you time. It's working. I just had to transform "users:id" -> users:users.id.